# How exactly does Standard Scaling a Sparse Matrix work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am currently reading "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras and TensorFlow" and came across a Tip stating "If you want to scale a sparse matrix without converting it to a dense matrix first, you can use a StandardScaler with its with_mean hyperparameter set to False: it will only divide the data by the standard deviation, without subtracting the mean (as this would break sparsity)." so I tried it out to understand what it is doing. However, the result does not seem to be scaled at all. I created a csr_matrix from a np.array and used a StandardScaler with with_mean=False as parameter. After that, I fit_transformed the matrix. The non-zero results are all the same and nothing is scaled. I don't even understand how the results are calculated. I thought the mean value is set to zero and we are scaling every non-zero value based on the standard deviation of its corresponding column but this method would've given me the scaled value 1.732 which is not the same as the output.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

X = csr_matrix(np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0], [3, 0, 0]]))
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
print(X_scaled)
print(X_scaled.toarray())


This outputs:

  (0, 2)    2.1213203435596424
  (1, 1)    2.1213203435596424
  (2, 0)    2.1213203435596424

[[0.         0.         2.12132034]
 [0.         2.12132034 0.        ]
 [2.12132034 0.         0.        ]]
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding something?

I'm not sure if this is what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `with_mean=False`, `StandardScaler` is only dividing each column by its standard deviation.
As you can see below, for any number `i`, this will return `2.12132...`

```
for i in range(1,4):
    s = np.std([0,0,i])
    print(f"{i} / {s:0.5f} = {i/s:0.5f}")

>>> 1 / 0.47140 = 2.12132
>>> 2 / 0.94281 = 2.12132
>>> 3 / 1.41421 = 2.12132
```